# Counting points inside polygons by attribute using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point-in-polygon, count

I am working with ArcMap 10.8 and extensions.

I have a grid (polygons) and another shapefile of points. I need to generate a field in the grid that shows me how many points are inside each cell, but grouped by a criterion.

For example suppose that the grid are "football stadiums" and players are points. The points shape has a field called "team". If in a specific stadium there are 34 players from 3 different teams, in the count field of polygons shape we will have 3.

With spatial join tool I can only count the total points within the polygons, but I cannot count by attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one such solution, using this test data, players are labelled with their "team name":

[image: Test data]

Run the spatial Join Tool but set the field map up as shown below:

[image: Field Map]
*Note the merge rule is set to JOIN and the delimiter is a comma*

The Output would be this:

[image: Output]

Now add a numeric field and run the following python in a field calculate tool:

```py
len(set(!team!.split(",")))
```

[image: Final result]