# Adding and visualizing unique values in raster dataset using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I want to make a raster dataset out of points.
I have all the points already visualized on a map.

The attribute table (of the point dataset) consists of names of species (and other fields).

I want to visualize the number of different species in each raster cell.
For example: In one cell are 4 different species.

How can I count the different species and make a raster dataset that visualizes this?

The tool that I used is the point to raster.
However, I cannot select **unique values** and count them.

Counting only the number of points in each raster cell is not enough.

Comment: Create a fishnet and do a spatial join, then if required convert to raster.

Comment: I also tried that. However, I cannot find a suitable merge rule, as I want to count the number of unique values in a cell (100X100 meter).

Comment: Have a look at my answer to another question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386594/counting-points-inside-polygons-by-attribute-using-arcmap/386605#386605).

Comment: @Hornbydd Thank you! It worked. I never thought of this.